# Custom SF Symbol is always filled with color

Tags: inkscape, sf-symbols

I'm trying to create a custom symbol. It looks fine in Inkscape, but when I import it into the SF-Symbol App, all regions are filled.

[This is the structure of the SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyKuH.jpg)

[And this is what SF-Symbols makes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq8pT.jpg)

So, one rect-shape is filled white, but after the import every shape is filled black.
What is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, for those struggling with this particular problem: Apples SF-Symbols only interprets paths correctly instead of other shapes. So an object to path operation solves the problem.

Paths instead rects:

[image]